# I took this code straight out of 'Java all in one for Dummies' ....why doesn't it work?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, imageicon

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Picture extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        new Picture();

    }

    public Picture(){

        this.setTitle("Picture");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon("TestImage.jpg");
        p.add(new JLabel(pic));
        this.add(p);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println(pic);
    }

}
```

This code as it is just displays a collapsed frame. I would expect that the pack(); method call would size the frame around my .jpg image, correct?

I can already hear the first question, and yes the image is in the same folder as my project package folder.

I am using the Eclipse IDE.

I also added the println(); statement to see what the Image reference returned and it returns "TestImage.jpg".
I thought it would return an address of the image in memory.??

I have been reading the forum all morning and I can't really find anything that helps me there without copying and using someone else's more complex code.
I am trying to keep this as simple as I can so that I don't confuse myself.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "I took this code straight out of 'Java all in one for Dummies' …why doesn't it work?"  ROFL  Best question title ever!  Thank you :)

Comment: Try doing `this.pack()` _after_ the `this.setVisible(true)` call. ;)

Comment: If that doesn't work, print `pic.getImage()`.

Comment: To answer a minor question:  `System.out.println(pic)` will print whatever text (String) the object's `.toString()` method returns.

Comment: No, the image dows not display.

Comment: If this image is supplied by the user, give them a `JFileChooser` to identify it.  If it is part of the application, use `getResource()`.

Comment: @JavainAlaska: Hopefully this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), be able to add more to your knowledge in your endeavour :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the image is in the same folder as my project package folder

That's it.

As written, your program looks for the image in the *current working directory*, not the package hierarchy.

From [the Javadoc for the constructor taking `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.lang.String%29), it reads the image from the specified filename, as desired. However, when you specify a relative path, that means to read relative to the working directory that the application is running in.

To work around this, you have 2 options:

- Specify the image filename relative to the working directory your IDE runs your program in. I believe Eclipse runs applications in the project root directory, and the source package hierarchy is rooted at `src`. In this case it'll work if you specify `src/TestImage.jpg`. The disadvantage is that if you ever run your program from a different directory, you'll have to move the image file along with it. This is inconvenient for distribution/packaging, because you can't just drop the JAR file and have it run.
- Use Java's resource loader to load the image file from the package hierarchy. To do this, first use

  ```
  getClass().getResource("TestImage.jpg")
  ```

  to get a URL for the image (relative to the package root). See that [`ImageIcon` has a constructor that accepts a URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.net.URL%29) to read the image from. So you should read the image using

  ```
  new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("TestImage.jpg"))
  ```

  The advantage of being relative to he package hierarchy is that the program can be run from any location, and the image can be bundled with your app in a single JAR file.

  Aside: it's best practice to create a package in which you place both code and resources (rather than just placing them in the package root). In that case, pass `"com/example/someapp/TestImage.jpg"` instead.

Comment: actually, in eclipse, this is the *current working directory*.

Comment: +1 for the explanation of the problem.  -1 for not discussing reasons to use `getResource()`.  Nice catch!

Comment: @RichardSitze: Edited with info on getResource.

Comment: new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("TestImage.jpg")); This Worked!! why would there not be some sort of exception when the file was not found?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail I mean if the path was wrong the way I had it in the first place, then it wasn't finding the file. Right? so how come there is no File not found exception?

Comment: `new javax.swing.ImageIcon("nonexistent/file.jpg")` throws no exception, so the libraries seem to be swallowing `FileNotFoundException` somewhere. I don't know why they designed it that way.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("TestImage.jpg"));
```

See [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) tutorial for more details, in particular [Loading Images Using getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource) section.

Comment: Why are you calling `getClass()` twice?